# Non-EU citizen applying EU Tourist visa with German Diplomat Spouse

Tags: visas, italy, german-citizens, filipino-citizens

I'm a non-EU citizen and getting married this year. After our wedding I am planning to vacation in Italy with my German diplomat husband-to-be. My passport will expire this month and I will apply for a new passport using my new last name (husband's last name) after the wedding.

I don't know the benefit of my fiancé's diplomatic passport?
Do I need to apply for a Tourist visa?
Do I need to attach his passport with my passport?
How long will it take to be processed?
If I need a Tourist visa, do I need to present my bank statements?
Or is it possible to present his bank statements?

Comment: Hi Pnuts, Im from Asia  and to be applying for my German Citizenship after our wedding with my German Fiance. Thanks

Comment: I'm Filipino citizen so obviously I'm non european citizen

Comment: Diplomatic passports generally don't confer benefits (or confer extremely limited benefits) unless you're in the country where the diplomat is posted, or you're in transit to or from that country. The point of the passport is official travel, and outside of official travel it's not so helpful (unless you happen to be a head of state, then you're pretty much good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, I don't think your husband's diplomatic passport makes any difference for this purpose. This also means that you probably need a visa.

But as the wife of an EU citizen, as long as you are travelling with him, that visa should be free of charge and you should not have to present any bank statement. On the regular [visa form](http://www.esteri.it/visti/pdf/formulario_visto_schengen_en.pdf) you can omit the fields marked with a ‘*’ and simply provide evidence of your relationship instead. See also [europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm).

Comment: All I need is to attach his Passport and our Marriage contract in my Tourist visa application without any bank statement, right? Thank you so much

Comment: @Leon_gabrielle In principle, yes.